# A finish(ing) touch

Tags: difference, adjectives

What is the difference in meaningwise between the two?

1. A finishing touch.
2. A finish touch.

You give a finishing touch to your job.

Comment: "2. A finish touch." needs context. This not a normal usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "finishing touch" is a last bit of detail, usually to some kind of creation. "Finish touch" is not a phrase commonly used in English.